# How to send parse push to devices near a particular geopoint & to a channel?

Tags: android, rest, parse-platform

I am using parse to push data to a set of android devices which are near a particular geopoint. I have successfully created a geopoint from the device into the installationData. I want to push data to a particular channel **and** filter by those devices near the geopoint. But when i push this data from REST API i get 400 Bad Request error:

```
{"where":{"channels":"NewTowRequests","user":{"$inQuery":{"location":{"$nearSphere":{"__type":"GeoPoint","latitude":30.0,"longitude":-20.0},"$maxDistanceInMiles":1.0}}}},"data":{"custid":118,"fromadd":"uuhuh","orderid":"BT8224847","type":"NewTowRequests","paymenttype":"Cash","custdevid":"APA91bEgSVTkS4M4YXJbIlRUx_8LfPMnnpvWKUEobHpO6bVZ-086n2uRalyeql98oy9ifyoUXARJuki1SEYIBCuHHIJXe8Jn9YLbQRQ3VdJqGEaDXFxRDys","fromlat":30.0,"fromlon":-20.0,"rating":0.0,"ordertype":"SCH","sch_date":"25/08/2015 16:00","is_sch":"True","status":"PEN","is_rec":"False","orderdate":"13/08/2015 07:38"}}
```

Note that i have not created any users , isn't there a method to send it to the devices near a geopoint without creating the users?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can. Parse push has to be to the users as far as I know, even for anonymous users which are still considered as users in Parse.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: What? He is asking "isn't there a method to send it to the devices near a geopoint without creating the users?" and I replied "I don't think you can." How does that not an answer? Uh, I just wanted to help but sometimes people just get harsh...

Answer (score 1):

[Parse](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#geopoints-pfgeopoint) allows you to associate real-world latitude and longitude coordinates with a particular device. From the information I got from the Parse documentation, by adding a GeoPoint to a Object, allows queries to take into account the proximity of an object to a reference point.

This allows you to easily do things like find out what user is closest to another user or which places are closest to a user.

[ParseGeoPoint](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseGeoPoint.html) represents a latitude / longitude point that may be associated with a key in a ParseObject or used as a reference point for geo queries. This allows proximity based queries on the key.

You can use something similar to the below:

```
ParseGeoPoint userLocation = (ParseGeoPoint) userObject.get("location");
ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("PlaceObject");
query.whereNear("location", userLocation);
query.setLimit(10);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() { ... })
```

[This](https://parse.com/questions/using-my-current-location-and-wherenear-or-wherewithinkilometers) might also help you :)

Comment: Sorry not a valid answer. As i said, i have not created ParseUsers and i want to somehow connect my installations to the geopoint since in the parse db i can see the geopoints table being associated with installationId and i have a separate table which keeps the installationId and other data. This points that , after some effort, the both can be connected to find devices near a particular geopoint. I need to find this code.. and i am using REST API. (see tag rest)

Comment: I think you still need to use anonymous users to achieve this. IE even if they are not registered with a name on your app, they need to have an identity.

Comment: The identity is very well there but handled on my own databse server. Basically our users do not have a password, its something like whatsapp. ParseUser needs to have username and password.